# How to properly say that a given day/date does not exist?

Tags: dates

I wanted to use this, but I don't know if it's actually valid in English:

> The specified date is invalid.
> It points to a non-existing day.

I'm not a native speaker, and I just want to say that the input points to a date that does not exist, like 30th February.

Comment: *The specified date is invalid* is perfect.  IF you are going to add the follow-on sentence it should be "*It refers to a non-existent day.*"  but I think your first sentence is fine all by itself.

Comment: @Jim That would make a perfect answer :)

Comment: In normal conversation, something like 'The 30th of January was a Saturday this year,' or even 'The 30th of _February_?' would be more idiomatic.

Comment: The term "non-existing day" is a quirk of date formats. You probably wouldn't say *Blahday* was a *non-existing day*, or a *day that doesn't exist*. I think it would be silly to have different error messages for, say, *30th February* and *28th Nebruary*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm using this in a website to display an error message.

Comment: Accepting an answer about 20 minutes after you have asked a question may decrease the chance of you getting the best possible answer or of getting a wide range of useful information. I care not personally, but some people are influenced by an answer having been accepted.

Comment: Since this is a validation message over a form input (I assume), you could just say "Please enter a valid date."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"The specified date is invalid." is not only valid, but quite common.

If you want to avoid "sounding like a robot", then you could take the invalid date in question and produce a sentence like:

> There is no 31<sup>st</sup> of April.
>
> There is no 29<sup>th</sup> of February in 2013.

Comment: I guess I'll just use the first sentence alone then, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

"The specified date is invalid" will be perfectly well understood by essentially everyone who encounters it as a website error message.

You'd probably get good understanding with the unusual but brief and informative

- No such day in calendar

If you wanted to be complete and/or pedantic you could say

- xxx is not a valid date

where xxx is the user input data.

This carries a very slightly stronger suggestion that what is wrong is the formatting or genuine-date nature of the entry.
 Without this the entry could be a properly formatted date entry and refer to a real-world day but still be "invalid".  For example,

Departure date ? : 11/11/2013
   Return date ? : 12/12/2012 -> The specified date is invalid
(Because return is before departure)

Date of birth ? : 11/11/1812 -> The specific date is invalid
(Because not even I am that old)

Even the above is not an absolute statement about date formatting or real-world date being invalid, but making this certain would require a much more complex and pedantic sentence, which is not justified or useful in the context of an error message.

Comment: A fun one is: “Where was Benjamin Franklin [1706–1790] on September 11th, 1752?”

Comment: @tchrist Thanks! I didn't know about this little slice of history. Very interesting.