# Is there a term for a date or date/time combination that doesn't exist?

Tags: word-choice, terminology

Three (possibly distinct) examples:

1. A date which never exists/existed, like February 31
2. A date which was 'skipped' because of calendar changes.  When Russia transitioned from the Julian to the Gregorian calendar it 'skipped' October 26, 1917, among other days.
3. A date/time which was 'skipped' due to a daylight savings change, like 02:01 on 03/27/2011 in the USA

These all appear to be properly formatted, but don't exist, at least in some parts of the planet that recognize the standard US date/time lexicon.

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101711/how-to-properly-say-that-a-given-day-date-does-not-exist) discusses the phrase to show to application users when they choose an `invalid date`, but `invalid date` would include `01/blah/-2` and other entries that don't conform to an accepted date format.

I've been using the term `irrational date`, but I'm not a mathematician and don't know if it is appropriate to compare these situations to irrational numbers.

Comment: "Invalid date" seems to be pretty widely used by the IT community, although the scope may be narrower than what you are looking for.

Comment: *Imaginary date* is what occurred to me.  At some point in the past, [some Wikipedia editor decided to use the term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/February_31), too.

Comment: The question this is marked as a duplicate of is along the same lines, but is asking for a phrase, presumably to display to a computer user.  I was (am) wondering if there's a single word or short term that describes this, like 'leap year'.  It appears there is not :).